# I need to map words from a text dataset and give them a score based on other dataset in a fast way

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have a text dataset of 2000 rows, each row contains nearly a page of English words, and I have written a function to split each row into words, give them a score based on another dataset, then take the average of scores for each row. so for example: 'Im a programmer' >> [15,20,25] >> mean = 20.
The problem is that the code is so slow and it takes nearly 30 minutes to run on the entire dataset. Is there a way to make it work faster?
Here is what I tried:

```
def get_score(text):
    word_arr = pd.Series(0, index=text.split(), dtype='float64', name='Count')
    return pd.merge(word_arr,
                    scoring,
                    how="left",
                    left_index=True,
                    right_index=True,)['count'].fillna(0).mean()

df['string'].apply(get_score)
```

Where `word_array` is a 0s pandas series with words as index, and `scoring` is a big series of scores with words as index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This the fastest solution I have found till now, it reduced time from 30mins to nearly 5-8 minutes.

```
def score_function(text):
    ser = pd.Series(index=text.split(' ')).index.intersection(scoring.index)
    values = scoring[ser]
    return values.sum()
```

Where `scoring` is a pandas series containing words as index and score as values.

Answer (score 0):

Without an ability to test this on your data, I can just suggest this method that uses simpler structures and methods:

```
import statistics
import pandas as pd

# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'string': ['first page of text word_wo_score', 'second page of text']}
)
df
#                               string
# 0   first page of text word_wo_score
# 1                second page of text

scoring = pd.Series([0,2,3,4,1], index=['first', 'page', 'of', 'text', 'second'])

# convert scoring values to a dictionary
scoring_dict = scoring.to_dict()
scoring_dict
# {'first': 0, 'page': 2, 'of': 3, 'text': 4, 'second': 1}

# convert your column to list
txt = df['string'].to_list()
txt
# ['first page of text word_wo_score', 'second page of text']

# map each word in each sublist to dict and take the mean of each new sublist
# if a word does not exist in the dictionary, it gets a score of 0
[statistics.mean([scoring_dict.get(word, 0) for word in page.split()]) for page in txt]
# [1.8, 2.5]
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, it's more simple and readable but the problem is that python ordinary structures and loops are much slower than Pandas and Numpy things specially with big iterations, that's why I'm trying to get thing into a Pandas series.
I don't know exactly the difference in mechanisms but I tried this function as well and it reduced time to 8 minutes:
` def score_new(text):
    ser = pd.Series(index=text.split(' ')).index.intersection(scoring.index)
    values = scoring[ser]
    return values.sum()  `
And then I divided the output by another series containing counts to get mean.